# Apparent paradox: Mass flow rate decreases when I increase nozzle diameter

Tags: fluid-dynamics, simulations, gas

I do computational fluid dynamics for a living. I have recently been working on a case in which I simulate the flow (assumed 2D) of a compressible gas from a large chamber at pressure $P_1$, through a small orifice which is $d$ meters wide, and then once again into a large chamber at pressure $P_2$. The physical quantities of interest to me are the pressure drop $P_1-P_2$, the gap size $d$, and the mass flow rate through the small orifice $\dot m$. In my case, the large chambers are about $5$ millimeters wide and the small gap is between $0.1$ and $1$ millimeters wide. The pressure drop ranges from $10^3$ Pascals to $10^4$ Pascals. Given below is a picture of what the geometry looks like (the fluid flows from left to right):

[image: geometry]

I notice a very strange phenomenon. At the higher pressure drops, I notice that there is a strange relationship between the gap size $d$ and the mass flow rate $\dot m$. For the smaller gap sizes, the mass flow rate appears to increase linearly with the gap size. But once the gap size goes from $7\cdot 10^{-4}$ to $8\cdot 10^{-4}$, there is a sudden drop. I initially thought that my simulations must not yet be sufficiently converged, but after running them for several more hours the trend persisted. Shown below is the mass flow rate plotted against the gap size, at a constant pressure drop of $10^4$ Pascals.

[image: plot]

---

**My question:**

Is there a physical reason why this would happen? Compressible gas dynamics are not my area of expertise, so I don't have the requisite knowledge to be able to tell if this is just bad simulation data or whether this reflects a real physical phenomenon. Could someone shed some light on this please?

Comment: My guess: there is something involving Reynolds number that enters a "transition" at the point that you are concerned about.